# Why are @property model definitions visible in list_display but not field_sets for Django Admin?

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

Why are `@property` definitions visible in `list_display` but not `field_sets` or `list_filter` for Django Admin?

Eg. in the example below `my_prop` displays perfectly in the admin as a `list_display` field but not as a field in a `field_set`

`models.py`:

```
class MyModel (models.Model):
       // code

     @property my_prop(self):
       // code
```

`admin.py`:

```
@admin.register(MyModel):
    class MyModelAdmin(AdminModel):
        list_display=('my_prop',)
        fieldsets = ( ('Summary',{ 'fields':('myprop',) }))
```

**Edit**

Thanks to [Iain Shelvington](https://stackoverflow.com/users/548562/iain-shelvington) who explained that `@property` is displayed as a `readonly_field` requirement in Django Admin.

Updated further with a real world example on how the `@property` is constructed in my example. Ideas welcome on how to filter this equivalent to a `list_filter` field in Django Admin!

```
closure_datetime = models.DateTimeField()

@property
def my_prop(self):
    if self.closure_datetime :
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Comment: You need to add `myprop` to `MyModelAdmin.readonly_fields` - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.readonly_fields

Comment: Thanks, that seems to work on my test for `list_display` but oddly not `list_filter`. Do you know why that would be?

Comment: `list_filter` is generally for model fields that can be filtered via a query. If you give an example of how `my_prop` is generated maybe I could suggest a way to filter it

Comment: `closure_datetime` must be nullable? Otherwise `my_prop` would always return `True`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add non-fields (like properties) to `readonly_fields` if you want them to be displayed on the admin edit page.

To add a filter that filters based on `closure_datetime` being null or not you can define a filter like this

```
class MyPropListFilter(admin.SimpleListFilter):
    title = 'My Prop'
    parameter_name = 'my_prop'

    def lookups(self, request, model_admin):
        return (
            ('true', 'True'),
            ('false', 'False'),
        )

    def queryset(self, request, queryset):
        if self.value() == 'true':
            return queryset.filter(closure_datetime__isnull=False)
        if self.value() == 'false':
            return queryset.filter(closure_datetime__isnull=True)
```

And add it to your admin like this

```
class MyModelAdmin(AdminModel):
    list_filter = [
        MyPropListFilter
    ]
```